# How to select entire column (or row) using keyboard

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

Using ag-grid (trying on the demonstration page https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php) how can I use the keyboard to select an entire column?
You can press (on the demo) Shift and down arrow and go all the way down, but it's not practical for 1000s of rows. And as soon as you press Control, the selected cell does become the most bottom cell, but you loose the selection (as if Shift wasn't pressed).

If I was in Excel, I would select the top cell in a column, press Control+Shift+Down arrow, the whole column is selected, I can now do Control+C to copy.

I have seen this article, that adds a new menu item to do it [How to select column data in ag-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69030124/how-to-select-column-data-in-ag-grid) . I know I could assign a shortcut to that action too, but ideally I need a keyboard way using the Control (Command on a mac) key.

Answer (score 0):

There's a not-so-straightforward way of doing this.

1. Click on the top most cell of the column you want to select
2. Do a `Control + A` (or `Command + A` for macOS) to select all of the grid
3. Now press `Shift+ALT+(Left Arrow and/or Right Arrow keys` or `Shift+Option+(Left Arrow and/or Right Arrow keys` in Mac OS

This should work

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful workaround. Doesn't work well for the end-user if they have 30 columns. I find that on PC in step 3 you don't need to press ALT, just shift+arrow. I'll try to find a programmatic way and share.